# Jackson LocalDate module registered still exception

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, localdate

I wanted to serialize list with different objects of the class `Person`with a `firstname`, `lastname` and a `birthday`. After looking at different questions in the forum here I found out that I need to register the `jsr.310.JavaTimeModule` to serialize the `LocalDate birthday`. I know there are many entries on this site regarding this topic but most of them say that registering the module is enough to handle the `LocalDate`.

This is my writer class:

```
public void write(){
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    Person p1 = new Person("Peter", "Griffin", LocalDate.of(1988,6,5));
    Person p2 = new Person("Lois", "Griffin", LocalDate.of(1997,9,22));

    personList.add(p1);
    personList.add(p2);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());

    try {
        writer.writeValue(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/File/Personen.json"), personList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my Reader class is:

```
 public void read(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        ArrayList<Person> liste = mapper.readValue(new FileInputStream("File/Personen.json"),
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Person.class));
        System.out.println(liste.get(0).getFirstname());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After reading the file I get a

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of java.time.LocalDate (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1988-06-05')
>    at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 4, column: 18] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->Person["birthday"])

I thought I don't need to do anything more than registering the `TimeModule`. Do I need to register a module for the reader as well? Or is there another problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly registered the `JavaTimeModule` with the
`ObjectMapper` in your `write()` method.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

But you forgot to register it with the `ObjectMapper` in your `read()` method.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

To fix it, just add the missing `.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())` there.

Or better yet:
Remove the local `ObjectMapper` definitions from your `write` and `read` methods.
Instead, add it as a member variable to your class, so that you can use
the same `ObjectMapper` instance in both methods.

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: thank you so much! Sometimes an exception distracts you from the obvious...